# jQuery Cycle with Lazy Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-7, lazy-loading, cycle

I'm using Drupal 7 and created slides via [jQuery Cycle.](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) 
JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#quicktabs-container-view__islerimiz__islerimiz > div').cycle({
    fx: 'fade',
    next:   '.next', 
    prev:   '.prev' ,
    timeout: 0,
  });
});
```

It work. My site horizontal parallax and all images loading in one time. So, I want to use [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) plugin.

```
$("img.lazy").lazyload();
```

Now, I have a problem. [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) work normal too but incompatible with [jQuery Cycle.](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) I see  get an slide image via [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload) but when I click navigation buttons of slide, don't get another images.

How can i make compatible [jQuery Cycle.](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)  and [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload)? Thanks.